# Android Firestore query paging FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, paging

I have a function that fetches posts from my firestore db and I am following the docs for paging a query by last index document but for some reason after first fetch when trying to run the next query I receive `com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain duplicate fields uploadTimeStamp`

I also logged and saw that the query seems ok and the `lastVisible` is actually index 4 in the documents list after running first query, but somehow in the second query I receive all first 5 posts again..

any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
suspend fun getMyPosts(userID: String): Flow<MutableList<DocumentSnapshot>> = flow {
        Log.d(TAG, "getMyPosts() called -> userID is $userID")
        var data: QuerySnapshot? = null
        try {
            data = dbRef.collection("posts")
                .whereEqualTo("userID", userID)
                .orderBy("uploadTimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(5)
                .get()
                .await()
            Log.d(TAG, "emitting ${data.documents.size} posts: \n")
            data.documents.forEach { doc ->
                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "post number ${data.documents.indexOf(doc)}, timestamp: ${doc.get("uploadTimeStamp")}"
                )
            }

            emit(data.documents)
            while (!data!!.isEmpty && data.size() == 5) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getting more posts")
                val lastVisible = data.documents[data.size() - 1]
                Log.d(TAG, "last index is ${data.size() - 1}")
                Log.d(TAG, "lastVisible is ${lastVisible.get("uploadTimeStamp")}")
                data = data.query
                    .whereEqualTo("userID", userID)
                    .orderBy("uploadTimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)
                    .limit(5)
                    .get()
                    .await()
                if (!data.isEmpty) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "emitting ${data.documents}")
                    emit(data.documents)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get MyPosts,\n $e")
            data!!.documents.forEach { doc ->
                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "post number ${data.documents.indexOf(doc)}, timestamp: ${doc.get("uploadTimeStamp")}"
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the logcat when i run `getMyPosts()` so you can see that I somehow get the first 5 docs again:

```
2021-06-03 12:31:33.349 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: getMyPosts() called -> userID is ncTe77npPHPJyQvJJdRUAY1fEBB3
2021-06-03 12:31:34.048 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: emitting 5 posts: 
2021-06-03 12:31:34.048 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 0, timestamp: 1622708658810
2021-06-03 12:31:34.048 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 1, timestamp: 1622708316148
2021-06-03 12:31:34.049 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 2, timestamp: 1622665878322
2021-06-03 12:31:34.049 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 3, timestamp: 1622665769466
2021-06-03 12:31:34.049 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 4, timestamp: 1622661053130
2021-06-03 12:31:34.082 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: getImages() called
2021-06-03 12:31:34.083 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: [false, false, true]
2021-06-03 12:31:35.345 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: [false, true, true]
2021-06-03 12:31:36.068 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: [true, true, true]
2021-06-03 12:31:37.084 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: [false, false, true]
2021-06-03 12:31:37.294 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: [false, false, true]
2021-06-03 12:31:37.500 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: getting more posts
2021-06-03 12:31:37.500 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: last index is 4
2021-06-03 12:31:37.501 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: lastVisible is 1622661053130
2021-06-03 12:31:37.666 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: Failed to get MyPosts,
     com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain duplicate fields uploadTimeStamp
2021-06-03 12:31:37.666 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 0, timestamp: 1622708658810
2021-06-03 12:31:37.666 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 1, timestamp: 1622708316148
2021-06-03 12:31:37.667 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 2, timestamp: 1622665878322
2021-06-03 12:31:37.667 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 3, timestamp: 1622665769466
2021-06-03 12:31:37.667 4990-5249/avedot.app D/AppRepository: post number 4, timestamp: 1622661053130
```

this is my firestore document structure

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify your code a bit, you're doing:

```
var data: QuerySnapshot? = null
try {
    data = dbRef.collection("posts")
        .whereEqualTo("userID", userID)
        .orderBy("uploadTimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(5)
        .get()
        .await()
    ...
    while (!data!!.isEmpty && data.size() == 5) {
        val lastVisible = data.documents[data.size() - 1]
        data = data.query
            .whereEqualTo("userID", userID)
            .orderBy("uploadTimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .startAfter(lastVisible)
            .limit(5)
            .get()
            .await()
```

So you're building `data` out from its original value, by calling `whereEqualTo` and `orderBy` **again** on it, which is what the error message is complaining about.

The simplest fix is to not re-use the existing value of data, so to change `data = data.query` to `data = dbRef.collection("posts")`.

But you seem to be trying a builder pattern, which is actually a better approach. You'll need to make sure in that case that you're not rebuilding the entire query, but only add the clauses that are relevant to the pagination section:

```
data = data.query
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .get()
    .await()
```

So here we're just adding the `startAfter` clause, as all other conditions were already present in the `data.query` as you first built it.

Comment: Thank you for marking it up for me that was really helpful!. Indeed my looping query saved the `orderBy` and `WhereEqualTo` from the first query so it pointed out as a duplicate so now things work fine

Comment: Good to hear. I do expect that doing another `data.query.startAfter(lastVisible)` would give problems btw. I typically keep a reference to the "base query" around, which is "everything except the `startAt`/`startAfter`", so that I can use that as the basis for pagination.